# How can i read MySQL data in loop with Offset C#

Tags: c#, mysql, loops

I try to get some Data from a MySQL database and try it like this but it dont work like i want. It should show me every time 1 row but now the for loop count to top and then it goes to the while loop. I just started programming and i know its maybe a simple solution but i cant find it.

```
Console.WriteLine("Getting Connection ...");
        MySqlConnection conn = DBUtils.GetDBConnection();

        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Openning Connection ...");

            conn.Open();
            MySqlCommand selectdata;
            selectdata = conn.CreateCommand();
            int i;
            for (i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
            {
                selectdata.CommandText = "SELECT `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `5`, `6`, `7` FROM `table` LIMIT 1 OFFSET " + i;
            }
            MySqlDataReader rdr = selectdata.ExecuteReader();
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                string a = Convert.ToString(rdr["1"]);
                string b = Convert.ToString(rdr["2"]);
                string c = Convert.ToString(rdr["3"]);
                string d = Convert.ToString(rdr["4"]);
                string e = Convert.ToString(rdr["5"]);
                string f = Convert.ToString(rdr["6"]);
                string g = Convert.ToString(rdr["7"]);


                // Print the data.
                Console.WriteLine(a + " " + b + " " + c + " " + d + " " + e + " " + f + " " + g);

            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: " + e.Message);
        }

        Console.Read();
    }
```

Solution for me:

```
Console.WriteLine("Getting Connection ...");
        MySqlConnection conn = DBUtils.GetDBConnection();

        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Openning Connection ...");

            conn.Open();
            MySqlCommand selectdata;
            selectdata = conn.CreateCommand();
            selectdata.CommandText = "SELECT `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `5`, `6`, `7` FROM `table` LIMIT 100000";
            MySqlDataReader rdr = selectdata.ExecuteReader();
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                string a = Convert.ToString(rdr["1"]);
                string b = Convert.ToString(rdr["2"]);
                string c = Convert.ToString(rdr["3"]);
                string d = Convert.ToString(rdr["4"]);
                string e = Convert.ToString(rdr["5"]);
                string f = Convert.ToString(rdr["6"]);
                string g = Convert.ToString(rdr["7"]);


                // Print the data.
                Console.WriteLine(a + " " + b + " " + c + " " + d + " " + e + " " + f + " " + g);
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);

            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: " + e.Message);
        }

        Console.Read();
    }
```

Comment: You are "replacing" the command text of the single command for 100000 times but at the last command text reads exactly as the first one

Comment: Also that code above cannot be compiled at all. You can't have a string variable named 1 or other number. Can you explain exactly what are you trying to do here?

Comment: Do you have a reason for needing to have sql command within a loop? If you don't, you could remove the 'for' loop entirely and change LIMIT 1 OFFSET " + i; to LIMIT 100000;

Comment: Just a very minor point - but if you know you are only getting 1 row back at most (LIMIT 1) then _"while (rdr.Read())"_ could be _"if (rdr.Read())"_

Comment: First of all I changed the names from my original script and edit it to numbers. correct it now.

Comment: and i dont need all at once and will add a sleeptimer to the script.

Answer (score 0):

This chunk of code runs quickly, even though it runs 100K times.

```
for (i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
{
  selectdata.CommandText = "SELECT `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `5`, `6`, `7` FROM `table` LIMIT 1 OFFSET " + i;
 }
```

At the end of it, you have a query containing this text.

```
  SELECT `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `5`, `6`, `7` FROM `table` LIMIT 1 OFFSET 99999
```

This query retrieves the hundred thousandth row from your table, according to some unpredictable ordering of the table.

(To get predictable ordering, you necessarily must provide an `ORDER BY` clause in your query. "Unpredictable" is like random but worse. Random implies a different ordering every time. Unpredictable means it stays the same, until it doesn't. When you're least expecting it to change.)

You then use the query, just once, in an `ExecuteReader()` method call. It returns just one row, even though your program is rigged up to accept an arbitrary number of rows with `while (rdr.Read())`.

Your columns have numbers for names. That's a bit strange.

You may want something like this.

```
for (i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
{
   selectdata.CommandText = "SELECT `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `5`, `6`, `7` FROM `table` LIMIT 1 OFFSET " + i;
   MySqlDataReader rdr = selectdata.ExecuteReader();
   while (rdr.Read())
   {
      string a = Convert.ToString(rdr["1"]);
      ...
      Console.WriteLine(a + " " + b + " " + c + " " + d + " " + e + " " + f + " " + g);
   }
}
```

in which you use each version of the SQL statement you create.

But this is a horrendously inefficient way to read a table.

Why not do this?

```
 selectdata.CommandText = "SELECT `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `5`, `6`, `7` FROM `table` LIMIT 100000;
 MySqlDataReader rdr = selectdata.ExecuteReader();
 while (rdr.Read())
 {
    string a = Convert.ToString(rdr["1"]);
    ...
    Console.WriteLine(a + " " + b + " " + c + " " + d + " " + e + " " + f + " " + g);
 }
```

Comment: yeah i know about the strange of numbers on colums.
i want it like this:
row1
wait 1 sec
row2
...
i will add a sleep timer later when the main problem is solved for me

Comment: Ok its my stupidity i just need to add the timer and everything worked as expected...

Comment: Holding open a Sql reader object for such a long time is probably a bad idea. A read operation on a table is done with transaction isolation; ordinarily you want to get in and get out when you read from a DBMS.  Read this. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-transaction-isolation-levels.html